# Python3 requests SSL

Tags: python, ssl

Недавно сменил *VDS*. Как следствие - перевыпустил `SSL сертификаты` для домена.
Все работает за исключением запросов к домену из под этого же сервера.

То-есть:
Есть *VDS*. Есть **API**, который поднят на этом же *VDS*.

(Все что написано далее выполняется на стороне этого же *VDS*)

```
import requests
requests.get("https://yandex.ru") # OK

# Далее обращаюсь к своему же API
requests.get("https://icyftl.ru/ctftime/teams/get/team/121175/id")
```

И вылетает:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='icyftl.ru', port=443): Max retries 
exceeded with url: /ctftime/teams/get/team/121175/id (Caused by 
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("hostname 'icyftl.ru' doesn't match 
'redmine.site.spb.ru'")))
```

Хотя если выполнить тот же код на моей стороне (с моей машины), то все хорошо.

`certifi` стоит и я честно не понимаю где искать проблему.

```
certifi==2020.6.20
```

Также пробовал с параметром `verify=False`

```
requests.get('https://icyftl.ru/ctftime/teams/get/team/121175/id',verify=False).text
```

```
/root/web/icyftl/caerme/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:979: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'icyftl.ru'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  <meta charset="utf-8" />\n  <title>Redmine 404 error</title>\n  <style>\n    body {font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif; color: #303030; margin: 10px;}\n    h1 {font-size:1.5em;}\n    p {font-size:0.8em;}\n  </style>\n</head>\n<body>\n  <h1>Page not found</h1>\n  <p>The page you were trying to access doesn\'t exist or has been removed.</p>\n  <p><a href="javascript:history.back()">Back</a></p>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

Comment: Сравните на какой IP ведёт адрес сайта на вашей машине и на VDS

Comment: Хм. IP разные. Получил трассировкой

Comment: @andreymal, не знаете с чем может быть связано?

Comment: Может как-то привязать это к DNS зоне, которую я менял у домена относительно недавно?

Comment: С содержимым файла /etc/hosts например? Обычно VDS для самого себя прописывает туда 127.0.0.1 и обычно это должно нормально работать

Comment: Ой, вей. Чет туплю. Действительно hosts все поломало